# Action of the Lorentz group on scalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, group-representations

The Lorentz groups act on the scalar fields as:
$\phi'(x)=\phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$

The conditions for an action of a group on a set are that the identity does nothing and that 
$(g_1g_2)s=g_1(g_2s)$. This second condition is not fulfilled because of the inverse on $\Lambda$. What is then the action of the Lorentz group on the scalar fields?

Comment: Would you mind writing out more carefully why the second condition isn't fulfilled?

Comment: $(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)^{-1}=\Lambda_2^{-1} \Lambda_1^{-1}$ which is not $\Lambda_1^{-1} \Lambda_2^{-1}$

Comment: It's OK, nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote by $g_1\phi$ the field transformed by the action of $\Lambda_1$ :  $$(g_1\phi)(x) = \phi(\Lambda_1^{-1}(x))$$  Similarly $g_2$ has action $$(g_2\psi)(x) = \psi(\Lambda_2^{-1}(x))$$  Substitute $g_1\phi$ for $\psi$  $$(g_2g_1\phi)(x) = (g_1\phi)(\Lambda_2^{-1}(x)) = \phi(\Lambda_1^{-1}\Lambda_2^{-1}(x)) = \phi((\Lambda_2\Lambda_1)^{-1}(x)) $$  So the group action looks correct.

Comment: +1, you forgot the subscripts on the first two lines, though it's not really unclear :)

Comment: Thank you, just to write it on the original notation: $(g_2g_1)\phi(x)=\phi((\Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)^{-1} x)=\phi(\Lambda_1^{-1}\Lambda_2^{-1} x)$, and $g_2(g_1\phi)(x)=g_1\phi(\Lambda_2^{-1} x)= \phi(\Lambda_1^{-1}\Lambda_2^{-1} x)$